# PHP: Processing an object of records, not just one record

Tags: php, web-services, actionscript-3, zend-framework, flex4

Currently, this service call only inserts a single (1) record. But I need to be able to send this method a true object with multiple records to be inserted during this call:

```
public function savePresentation($assets) {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "INSERT INTO $this->tablename (presentationid, assetid, positionid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iii', $assets->presentationid, $assets->assetid, $assets->positionid);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
    mysqli_close($this->connection);

    return $autoid;
}
```

How would I change this so that I can pass an associative array, or something similar?

I've tried wrapping the statement in a `foreach` statement, but it doesn't seem to work. :/

**NOTE**: I'm sending the data from Flash, if that matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use error_log(print_r( $asset, true )) - this will dump the structure of your passed object out to the PHP log. Then you can use foreach or for / next or whatever to loop through it. Maybe you're trying to loop on a structure that doesn't exist or is formatted differently when it gets passed in?

Its totally fine to pass complex objects from Flash/Flex into PHP. No reason you can't do what you're trying here.